# Find the $n^{th}$ term of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the following sequence of numbers

> 1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 21, 25, 27, 31, 33, 37, 43, 45, 49, 51, 55, 57, 63, 67, 69, 73, 75, 79, 85, 91, 93, 97, 99

Can anyone show me the calulation for the nth term?

The sequence of first differences can be seen to repeat 2 sets of numbers

> 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, **6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4**, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, **6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4**, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2

I'm mucking about with codes for my lower level students just for fun - then realised I couldn't actually $n$th sequence the code I'd created - oops!

Thanks!

Comment: The sequence of differences is periodic with period 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6. Find a formula for that sequence. Then your original sequence is simply 1 plus the sum of the differences.

Comment: You made an error, I think. You have two adjacent first differences of 6:  $85 - 79 = 91 - 85 = 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Call the sequence $a(n)$ with $n$ starting from $0$. Then$$a(12n)=42n+1$$ $$a(12n+1)=42n+3$$$$a(12n+2)=42n+7$$ $$...$$$$a(12n+11)=42n+37$$